# Yii2 RBAC Как узнать роль пользователя?

Tags: php, yii2

Работаю с RBAC в Yii2.
Существует иерархия юзеров сайта.
Если совсем грубо пользователь -> редактор -> админ
То-есть редактор наследует права пользователя, а админ наследует права редактора.
Мне нужно сделать, например, условие что наш юзер является именно редактором, не админом.
Как сделано сейчас:

```
Yii::$app->user->can('редактор') && !Yii::$app->user->can('админ')
```

Можно как-нибудь сделать одной командой, вроде `Yii::$app->user->is('редактор')` или что-то подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким же вопросом недавно задался. Единственное что я смог придумать это написал статичный класс хелпер с методом:

```
public static function currentUserRoleIs($name) {
    $userRole = current(ArrayHelper::getColumn(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->id), 'name'));
    return $name == $userRole;
}
```

Костыль наверное, но лучшего способа я не нашел...

Comment: Благодарю! Видимо, тоже так сделаю

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно нарушена архитектура ролей, если возникает такая сложность. Админу не обязательно наследовать роль редактора, можно просто для админа добавить такие же пермишены, как у редактора. Админ, все таки отдельная и самостоятельная роль, которая не должна зависеть от других ролей. Я бы сделал что-то подобное:

Проверятор - Модератор - Администратор

Вычитыватель - Редактор - Журналист

Comment: Такое решение тоже имеет право быть. Возможно я сделаю роли все в одной плоскости, без наследований. А вместо наследования сделаю общие пермишены

Comment: В данный момент на проекте пермишены создаются на каждый контроллер, потому что очень много пользователей с разным уровнем доступа. Следовательно несколько веток ролей и для каждой роли свои пермишены.